# Any Wysiwyg tool to edit wordpress site based on given theme?

Tags: wysiwyg

I dream of a wordpress dashboard that would be mostly Wysiwyg and let the user edit a site based on a given theme.

In fact this is something I know is technically possible as I have seen it in this tool:
http://visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/features.php   (see the video; it is not a wordpress tool, but it shows how one can edit a webpage underlying code with a Wysiwyg interface).

For example if I am using WooThemes Optimize, the dashboard would show me the homepage and let me edit the titles, the text in the button, the featured image, etc.

Does anyone know a tool that can do that? or any hint how I can get there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found this:
http://www.spiderwebpress.com/

apparently they call this a "WYSIWYG theme platform".

http://www.pagelines.com/